# Decorator Pattern - undefined constructor

Tags: java, constructor, undefined, decorator, implements

I have a liitle problem with my code. Everything looks good but when I trying to start program I see this:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor Pakiety(Samochod) is undefined
    The constructor Pakiet2(Samochod) is undefined
    The constructor Pakiet3(Samochod) is undefined

```
at SamochodInfo.main(SamochodInfo.java:16)"
```

There is code, comments and classes are in Polish cuz it's my homework. Help me please. :)

First class:

```
//Definiujemy klasę abstrakcyjną
abstract class Samochod {
protected String opis;

public String getOpis() {
    return opis;
}

public abstract double cena(); 

@Override //Nadpisanie metody
public String toString() {
    return cena() + "(" + getOpis() + ")";


}
}
```

Second class:

```
class Audi extends Samochod {

public Audi() {
    opis = "Podstawowa wersja samochodu z wyposażeniem standarowym";
}
@Override
public double cena() {
    return 75.000;
    }
}
```

Third class:

```
abstract class DekoratorSamochodu extends Samochod {
    protected Samochod car;

public DekoratorSamochodu(Samochod car) {
    this.car = car;
}

@Override
public abstract String getOpis();
}
```

Fourth class:

```
class Pakiety extends DekoratorSamochodu {

public Pakiety(DekoratorSamochodu car) {
    super(car);
}

@Override // Nadpisanie metody Opis (analogicznie w innych pakietach)
public String getOpis() {
    return car.getOpis() + ", Pakiet Smart";
}

@Override // Nadpisanie metody cena - cena zwiększy się o 10tyś. zł 
(analogicznie w innych
            // pakietach)
public double cena() {
    return car.cena() + 10.000;
}
}

class Pakiet2 extends DekoratorSamochodu {

public Pakiet2(DekoratorSamochodu car) {
    super(car);
}

@Override
public String getOpis() {
    return car.getOpis() + ", Pakiet Wygoda";
}

@Override
public double cena() {
    return car.cena() + 25.000;
}
}

class Pakiet3 extends DekoratorSamochodu {

public Pakiet3(DekoratorSamochodu car) {
    super(car);
}

@Override
public String getOpis() {
    return car.getOpis() + ", Pakiet Exclusive";
}

@Override
public double cena() {
    return car.cena() + 37.000;
}
}
```

Fifth class:

```
import java.util.List;

import java.util.*;

public class SamochodInfo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Samochod car;
    List<Samochod> info = new ArrayList<>();

//Wyświetlenie podstawowej wersi Audi
    car = new Audi();
    info.add(car);

//Wyświetlenie pierwszego pakietu Audi - smart
    car = new Audi();
    car = new Pakiety(car);
    info.add(car);

//Wyświetlenie druiego pakietu Audi - wygoda
    car = new Audi();
    car = new Pakiet2(car);
    info.add(car);

//Wyświetlenie trzecieko pakietu Audi - exclusive
    car = new Audi();
    car = new Pakiet3(car);
    info.add(car);

    for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
        int infoNr = i+1;
        System.out.println("Informacje o samochodzie " + infoNr + ":");
        System.out.println(" * " + info.get(i));
    } 


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`car` is of type `Samohod` and class `Pakety` doesn't have constructor that accepts `Samohod` it's only constructor accepts `DekoratorSamochodu`. You need to either add another constructor or change constructors of `Pakiety`, `Pakiet2` and `Packiet3` to accept `Samohod` instead of `DekoratorSamochodu`

Comment: Thank you so much!